# XAML DataTrigger not updating

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to change the colour of a button when a property in the datasource changes. Initialising the background colour works correctly based on the initial value of the `IsFilterOn` property but it isn't updating when the property changes.

The XAML

```
<FlexLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Filters}">
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button>
                <Button.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFilterOn}" TargetType="Button" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{Binding UpColour}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFilterOn}" TargetType="Button" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{Binding DownColour}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Button.Triggers>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</FlexLayout>
```

`Filters` is an `ObservableCollection<FilterModel>`:

```
public class FilterModel
{
    public string UpColour { get; set; }
    public string DownColour { get; set; }
    public bool IsFilterOn { get; set; }
}
```

Tapping a button correctly updates the `IsFilterOn` property for the button (code not shown) but the UI doesn't change to reflect it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Most likely because the function to change the UI is not invoked/running on the UI thread. It’s difficult to help more without seeing what UI code you have/what you’re trying to update. “Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread” check this out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.begininvokeonmainthread?view=xamarin-forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot see how you are updating the `IsFilterOn` property from `true` to `false` but if you are directly changing the property of one of the `FilterModel` instances in the list, then the property changed event will not be invoked.

The `ObservableCollection` will execute property changed events when you add or remove something from the list, but it is not watching objects' properties.

You have 2 options, either invoke Property Changed events from your `FilterModel` anytime `IsFilterOn` is updated or change all of the property values you need to and then manually execute property changed on the list. If you are updating multiple `FilterModel`s at the same time, performance would probably be better with the second option.

Option 1:

```
public class FilterModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public string UpColour { get; set; }
    public string DownColour { get; set; }

    private bool _isFilterOn = false;
    public bool IsFilterOn {
        get { return _isFilterOn; }
        set {
            _isFilterOn = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(); // Anytime this property is changed Property Changed will be executed
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Option 2:

```
public class FilterViewModel {
    private ObservableCollection<FilterModel> _filters;
    public ObservableCollection<FilterModel> Filters {
        get => _filters ?? (_filters = new ObservableCollection<FilterModel>());
        set {
            _filters = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public void ToggleFilters() {
        // some logic

        Filters[0].IsFilterOn = true; // Make all property changes

        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Filters)); // Tell the UI that the list has been updated and to refresh the data
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are correct. That was a bit of a facepalm moment, thanks for the reminder. Added PropertyChanged.Fody and it all started working.